# Problem installing R package from github, get"ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'"

Tags: c++, r, gcc, rcpp, gfortran

I'm new to Rcpp. I'm trying to install a package from github. By the instruction of README.md,

```
# Install release version from CRAN
install.packages("devtools")
# Install development version from GitHub
devtools::install_github("shuangj00/IntegrativeBayes")
```

I got warnings when running these codes:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lquadmath
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [IntegrativeBayes.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘IntegrativeBayes’
```

I have been stuck at the very beginning (installing the package) for the whole afternoon. Anyone knows how this could be fixed?

Comment: Have you compiled a package from source on your macOS machine?  There are many other steps you need besides installing `devtools`.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Hi Dirk, this is my first time trying to install a package from GitHub. BTW I watched your Rcpp tutorial on YouTube today, it helped a lot!

Comment: Hi @Yanghong -- glad you liked the video. I am not a macOS user but you probably need to read up on what to do next. There is a mailing r-sig-mac for R on macOS to ask some power users.